# ReactJs-Firebase Sms Authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Can somebody help me with implementing firebase SMS authentication in Reactjs using hooks

Kindly provide me with already working code or improve in the sandbox code.

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-dan-u7kd4?file=/src/App.js)